Is This Equivalent to the Standard $\epsilon$-$\delta$ Definition?
While reviewing real analysis, I find the traditional $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity somewhat cumbersome, as it often requires a two-step process: first finding an appropriate $\delta$ for a given $\epsilon$, and then verifying that this $\delta$ works. This inspired me to consider an alternative characterization.
Theorem
Let $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $. I am interested in whether the following is true:
$$
f \text{ is continuous at } a \iff \exists \, o(\delta) \text{ with } o(\delta) \to 0 \text{ as } \delta \to 0, \text{ such that } |f(x) - f(a)| \leq o(\delta) \text{ whenever } |x - a| < \delta.
$$
Observations

Backward Direction: If there exists a function $o(\delta) \to 0$ as $\delta \to 0$ that bounds $|f(x) - f(a)|$ whenever $|x - a| < \delta$, then $f$ must be continuous at $a$.
Proof: For any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a $\delta > 0$ such that $o(\delta) < \epsilon$. Then, for $ |x - a| < \delta $, we have:
$$
|f(x) - f(a)| \leq o(\delta) < \epsilon,
$$
satisfying the standard $\epsilon$-$\delta$ condition.

Forward Direction: I considered proving this by contradiction or contraposition, but a direct approach might be more effective. Specifically, defining $o(\delta) = \sup_{x \in (a - \delta, a + \delta)} |f(x) - f(a)|$ might show that if $f$ is continuous at $a$, then $o(\delta) \to 0$ as $\delta \to 0$.


Example: $ f(x) = x^2 $ at $ a $
Let $ f(x) = x^2 $. We want to show that $ f(x) \to a^2 $ as $ x \to a $:

We have $|f(x) - f(a)| = |x^2 - a^2| = |x - a||x + a|$.
If $ |x - a| < \delta $, we can bound $|x + a|$ by $2|a| + \delta$ and set $o(\delta) = \delta(2|a| + \delta)$.
As $\delta \to 0$, $ o(\delta) \to 0 $, showing that $f(x) = x^2$ meets the alternative continuity condition.

Questions

Does the forward direction hold? Does continuity imply the existence of such an $o(\delta)$ function?

Are there any restrictions or subtleties that this alternative definition introduces?

Is this formulation discussed in the literature? Any references exploring continuity in terms of bounds like $o(\delta)$ would be appreciated.


Thank you for your insights! I hope this approach offers a more intuitive perspective on continuity.
Edit
Thank you for your feedback! I appreciate your point about the work involved in proving that $ o(\delta) \to 0 $.
To clarify my thought process, let’s consider a simple example:
Let $ f(x) = 3x $. We want to show that $ f $ is continuous at a point $ a $.
Using the traditional $ \epsilon $-$ \delta $ definition of continuity, we need to show that for every $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists a $ \delta > 0 $ such that if $ |x - a| < \delta $. So, I need to come up with a candidate for $\delta$. Since $ |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon $, calculating the difference:
$$
|f(x) - f(a)| = |3x - 3a| = 3|x - a|.
$$
To satisfy the $ \epsilon $-condition, we can set:
$$
3|x - a| < \epsilon.
$$
Dividing both sides by 3, we find a candidate for our desired $ \delta $:
$$
\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3}.
$$
However, I must emphasize that after finding this candidate, I need to verify that it indeed satisfies the original requirement. I must repeat the process to confirm that whenever $ |x - a| < \delta $, we have:
$$
|f(x) - f(a)| = 3|x - a| < \epsilon.
$$
This two-step process—finding a candidate for $ \delta $ and then verifying it—can be cumbersome, especially for more complicated functions. It might not be immediately obvious that I need to divide by a factor of 3; determining the appropriate relationship can require additional steps to isolate and identify the correct $ \delta(\epsilon) $.
With this alternative definition, I will stop at
$$
|f(x) - f(a)| = |3x - 3a| = 3|x - a|=3\delta=o(\delta).
$$
No need to verify that this $\delta$ is the desired candidate. For the examples I tried, it is easy to show that $o(\delta)\rightarrow 0$ by the algebraic limit thereom.
Edit 2
As some commenters pointed out, using $o(\delta) \to 0$ as $\delta \to 0$ does imply defining convergence, which traditionally involves the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ approach. However, in this context, I intended $o(\delta) \to 0$ to be understood in terms of the sequential definition of convergence. Specifically, if we consider a sequence $\delta_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, then $o(\delta_n) \to 0$ under that assumption. For clarity, I’ve omitted the subscript $n$ here, but formally it should be $o(\delta_n) \to 0$ for any sequence $\delta_n \to 0$.
This approach also enables me to use algebraic limit theorems to demonstrate that $o(\delta_n) \to 0$. For instance, if $o(\delta_n) = \delta_n^2$, then I can write $\lim \delta_n^2 = \lim \delta_n \cdot \lim \delta_n = 0$. Thus, viewing it as a sequential limit simplifies proving such convergence properties.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

To answer your question 1 about proving the forward direction:
Since $f$ is continuous at $x=a$, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta’>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon/2$ for all $x\in (a-\delta’,a+\delta’)$. Then, for any $0\le\delta<\delta’$, we have
$$
0\le o(\delta) = \sup_{x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)} |f(x)-f(a)| \le \sup_{x\in (a-\delta’,a+\delta’)} |f(x)-f(a)| \le \epsilon/2 < \epsilon.
$$
Therefore, $o(\delta)\rightarrow 0$ as $\delta\rightarrow 0$.

Answer to question 2 (at the OP's request):
I don't think there are any subtleties in the definition of $o(\delta)$. The definition that the OP gave is well-defined for any $\delta\ge0$. Also, there's not much difference between strict vs non-strict inequality. If $o(\delta)$ gives a non-strict inequality, one can replace it with $2o(\delta)$ to get a strict inequality without affecting any conclusions.

Can you elaborate more on how the inequality leads to implies the conclusion you gave?

@abc1455 I basically showed that for any $\epsilon$, there is a $\delta’>0$ such that for all $0\le \delta < \delta’$, we have $0\le o(\delta) < \epsilon$. That’s the definition of $o(\delta)$  converging to $0$.

I understand the part that $\forall \epsilon>0$, $0\leq o(\delta)<\epsilon$ means that $o(\delta)\rightarrow 0$, but how does this mean that $\delta \rightarrow 0$.

@abc1455 I don’t understand what’s confusing you. It’s for all $0\le \delta < \delta’$, which clearly includes any $\delta \rightarrow 0$.

Okay. Thank you, It is just that the statement has lots of quantifiers, making it difficult to get which quantifier is for which part.

Regarding the second part, is there any restriction or some condition? For example, $o(\delta)$ might not be defined on the whole of $R^+$ but only locally, and is it better to make the statement $|f(x)-f(a)|<o(\delta)$ with a strict inequality? Furthermore, do you know an answer for the last part? And if it is easier to use this definition instead of the standard $\epsilon-\delta$ definition?

You already have an example of $o(\delta)$ using supremum which works for any $\delta\ge 0$, so I don’t think there’s any restriction. Also, strict vs non-strict isn’t a big deal: if $o$ gives only non-strict inequality, then $2o$ gives a strict inequality without affecting any conclusions. I don’t have an opinion about which definition is easier. It depends a lot on the context.

Sorry if I am asking a lot of questions, but have you seen this definition in some book before? If so, can you tell me this book?

@abc1455 Nope, I haven't seen it before.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
